# How, if possible, could I recover my Deleted History in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

I have just accidentally deleted my Google Chrome History.

Is anyone aware of any recovery options? I am aware that I could access my History via my Google Account but would ideally want the entries back in my Google Chrome Browser.

I have tried a System Restore but to no success.  I understand that there are a few questions, similar to this, already on this site.  That said, they are several years old.  Just wondering if anyone had come across any tried and tested methods?

Comment: If you don't have a backup of the user profile directory then you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  When you say the 'User Profile Directory', are you referring to local folders/files or the Google User Profile itself?  If you are referring to locally saved Folders/Files, then shouldn't a System Restore had worked?

Comment: System Restore is not a true backup. You have to make those separately, consciously, for when you need them... like now.